# How do I check what is in "device.calendar.ongoing" in on{x}?

Tags: javascript, android, onx

I want log the data in `device.calendar.ongoing` so I can debug a problem with my script. I have tried

```
if (device.calendar.ongoing.length > 0) {
    console.log("All items: " + JSON.stringify(device.calendar.ongoing));
}
```

but that returned

> All items: [{}]

When I did

```
if (device.calendar.ongoing.length > 0) {
    console.log("All items: " + device.calendar.ongoing);
}
```

But that returned

> All items: 0

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure anything is inside of "device.calendar.ongoing"?

Comment: Yes, this is all wrapped in an if length > 0 statement. I have updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter if "device.calendar.ongoing" has an empty object inside, it still has a length of > 0. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hsCny/

Comment: From what i saw over here https://www.onx.ms/#apiPage/calendar , `ongoing` - returns appointments that started before the current time and end after it. Do you have any appointments that meet these criterias?

Comment: I am running this during an appointment.

Comment: Looks like the root cause of my questions might be due to a bug in on{x}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for an unknown reason stringify doen't always work with on{x}. I use

```
var events = device.calendar.ongoing;
for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    console.log(events[i].title+": "+events[i].description);
}
```

this works in my cases.